# Scrollbars and flexbox min-width bug on chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

I'm having issues with a quirk in the way scrollbars are interacting with flexbox in Chrome. It doesn't happen on other browsers for me.

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner-left">
        <div class="one">
            <!-- content one -->
            <div style="height: 200px;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="two" style="min-width: 400px;">
            <!-- content two -->
            <div style="height: 200px;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.outer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.inner-left {
    background-color: green;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    padding: 15px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.inner-right {
    background-color: red;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 100px;
}

.one {
    background-color: orange;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.two {
    background-color: yellow;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

Now see the three pictures below which interactively show a resize as the window frame is moved really slowly left until the red box contacts the yellow box.

Observe a few things;

- In each example the scrollbar occupies space from different areas, either by creating new space or overlapping existing space. This means it would overlap content in the bottom green or bottom yellow areas during the 2nd frame.
- A second scroll bar appears momentarily in a specific spot of the resize.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4cmoeo28/

(1) Before edge collides with yellow box:

[image]

(2) During collision with yellow box:

[image]

(3) After collision with yellow box:

[image]

What's going on? Is there a way I can fix it up so the behaviour is consistent and that the 3rd frame is the one displayed the moment the yellow box contacts the red one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this, it seems working good.

http://jsfiddle.net/4cmoeo28/1/

```
.inner-left {
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Or, do it as non-flex, note the red background applied to the `outer` instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/4cmoeo28/3/

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.outer {
    background-color: red;
}

.outer:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.inner-left {
    background-color: green;
    padding: 15px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
}

.inner-right {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}

.one {
    background-color: orange;
    width: 100%;
}

.two {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner-left">
        <div class="one">
            <!-- content one -->
            <div style="height: 200px;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="two">
            <!-- content two -->
            <div style="height: 200px;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Kind of, but doesn't fix the problem of the scroll bar taking up some of the green padding area rather than making its own space if you resize it very carefully. This is an issue because in my application this consistently happens without the user resizing and I have another container below which is overlapped by the scrollbar when this happens. Thanks though!

Comment: I see what you mean, and couldn't figure out why, sounds like a chrome bug to me,  I also added another approach into the answer, which works exactly the same without flex.